# TinyMCE Editor causing ERR_BLOCKED_BY_XSS_AUDITOR in Chrome

Tags: tinymce, xss

I am working on a site that uses a TinyMCE Editor to allow users to add and write their own content.

Anyway, all seems okay until they try to embed a video using an `<iframe>` as when the form is submitted Google Chrome takes this code as malicious script and blocks the page from running, a refresh does by-pass this.

In my headers I could change `X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block` to just not block XSS but this seems slightly insecure and not much of a solution.

Is there a way to white list such things for TinyMCE Editors?

Essentially how does WordPress and the like get around this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this or did you just block the XSS protection?